# При прикосновении к триггеру кнопки не меняют статус

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что при активации триггера, состояние кнопок не изменяется, несмотря на наличие установленных коллайдеров, активированных триггеров и наличие соответствующих скриптов. Возможно, я допустил ошибку в каком-то месте, но в консоли нет никаких ошибок. В комментариях к коду я подробно описал все детали -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonProverka : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform target;
    [SerializeField] Transform button;
    [SerializeField] Camera cam;

    private bool hasTouchedPlayer = false; 

    public Button[] buttons; // массив кнопок

    void Start()
    { 
        SetButtonsInteractable(false); // деактивация кнопок в начале
    }

    // состояние кнопок
    private void SetButtonsInteractable(bool isInteractable)
    {
        foreach (Button button in buttons)
        {
            button.interactable = isInteractable;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 targetOnScreen = calculateScreenPosition(target.position, cam);
        button.position = targetOnScreen;
        button.gameObject.SetActive(targetOnScreen != Vector3.zero);
    }

    private Vector3 calculateScreenPosition(Vector3 position, Camera camera)
    {
        Vector3 heading = position - camera.transform.position;
        if (Vector3.Dot(camera.transform.forward, heading) > 0)
        {
            return camera.WorldToScreenPoint(position);
        }
        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    // метод при касании триггера
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            hasTouchedPlayer = true;

            // включаем кнопки при входе в триггер
            SetButtonsInteractable(true);
        }
    }

    // метод при выходе из триггера
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            hasTouchedPlayer = false;

            // выключаем кнопки при выходе
            SetButtonsInteractable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы `OnTrigger` работали нужно установить на один объект `rigidbody` без `isTrigger`, а на второй нужен `isTrigger` (Скрипт на тот у которого rigidbody). У вас также?

Comment: Точно, я забыл Rigidbody установить!!! Благодарю вас! Можете добавить ответ на данный вопрос, выберу его как решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы `OnTrigger` работали необходимо установить на первом объекте `rigidbody` без `isTrigger` в коллайдере, а на втором объекте нужно установить `isTrigger` в коллайдере.